# Comparing two Lists with Strings and Sublists in them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am stuck in a situation where I have to compare a list of lists where each sublist contains two strings and a sub-sublist. I want to compare each sublist to next sublist and record their first string and the matching identifiers in the third item (sub-sublist). It looks a bit confusing. Here is the example:
I have the following list of lists:

```
node = [['1001', '2008-01-06T02:12:13Z', ['']], 
        ['1002', '2008-01-06T02:13:55Z', ['']],  
        ['1003', '2008-01-06T02:13:00Z', ['Lion', 'Rhinoceros', 'Leopard', 'Panda']], 
        ['1004', '2008-01-06T02:15:20Z', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Eagle', 'Panda', 'Tiger']], 
        ['1005', '2008-01-06T02:15:48Z', ['Lion', 'Panda', 'Cheetah', 'Goat', 'Tiger']], 
        ['1006', '2008-01-06T02:13:30Z', ['']], 
        ['1007', '2008-01-06T02:13:38Z', ['Cheetah', 'Tiger', 'Goat']]]
```

The first item of each sublist is an ID, second item is timestamp, and third item (sub-sublist) contains the members. I want to compare the members and if two sublists contain same members, I want to store them in a new list as follows along with their IDs.

```
output-list = [['1003', '1004', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Panda']], 
               ['1003', '1005', ['Lion', 'Panda']], 
               ['1004', '1005', ['Lion', 'Panda', 'Tiger']], 
               ['1004', '1007', ['Tiger']], 
               ['1005', '1007', ['Cheetah', 'Goat', 'Tiger']]]
```

My head is not getting around it how to make a double for loop or any other way of doing it. Can anyone help me here please? Sorry I cannot produce a trying code.

Comment: Break down your code to the core, where you do the comparision, that's why you are fonfused.

Comment: Why don't you match `1001` with `1002`? `1001` with `1006`, `1002` with `1006`? These all have one match: the emoty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way if the order in the matching list is important.

```
>>> out  = []
>>> for ii, elem in enumerate(node[:-1]):                                                                                                            
...     for jj in range(ii + 1, len(node)):                                                                                                          
...         common = [subelem for subelem in elem[-1] if subelem in node[jj][-1]]
...         if len(common) > 0 and common != ['']:
...             out.append([elem[0], node[jj][0], common])                                                                                       
... 
>>> for elem in out:
...     print elem
... 
['1003', '1004', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Panda']]
['1003', '1005', ['Lion', 'Panda']]
['1004', '1005', ['Lion', 'Panda', 'Tiger']]
['1004', '1007', ['Tiger']]
['1005', '1007', ['Cheetah', 'Goat', 'Tiger']]
```

If order is not important and the lists are big use `set intersection` for the first line in the double loop as below

```
common = list(set(elem[-1]).intersection(set(node[jj][-1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a md5 hash for every list and compare them, just like a checksum.

`node_md5hash = hashlib.md5(bencode.bencode(node)).hexdigest()
output-list_md5hash = hashlib.md5(bencode.bencode(output-list)).hexdigest()`

And it would give you an md5 hash for node and for output-list and if the hashes are the same, so are their values.

**You will need to import the hashlib library and the bencode library (you will probably have to pip install bencode).**

Comment: I like this solution better than element-by-element solutions, but you can do it without including md5.  Python has built-in hashing for immutable types.  You can just `hash(tuple(<your list>))`.  If you want list comparisons to be independent of order, use `hash(tuple(sorted(<your list>)))`.

Comment: I should add that the built-in hash function only guarantees consistent values within a running kernel session.  If you need to *save* hashes, e.g. to disk, for comparison later, then md5 is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it:

```
node = [['1001', '2008-01-06T02:12:13Z', ['']],
        ['1002', '2008-01-06T02:13:55Z', ['']],
        ['1003', '2008-01-06T02:13:00Z', ['Lion', 'Rhinoceros', 'Leopard', 'Panda']],
        ['1004', '2008-01-06T02:15:20Z', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Eagle', 'Panda', 'Tiger']],
        ['1005', '2008-01-06T02:15:48Z', ['Lion', 'Panda', 'Cheetah', 'Goat', 'Tiger']],
        ['1006', '2008-01-06T02:13:30Z', ['']],
        ['1007', '2008-01-06T02:13:38Z', ['Cheetah', 'Tiger', 'Goat']]]
# Use this list for result
result = []

def city_exists(city, cities):
    """ Just a helper to verify if city already used """
    for c in cities:
        if c[1] == city:
            return True
    return False

# And finally, iterate and add to the resulting list
for item in node:
    for city in item[2]:
        if not city_exists(city, result):
            result.append([item[0], city])

# Print out the result
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are looking for is itertools.combinations which comes with python

```
di={i[0]:set(i[2]) for i in node};outputlist=[]
for i,j in itertools.combinations(di.keys(),2):
    union=list(di[i].intersection(di[j]))
    if union and not union[0]=='':#makes sure it is not an empty set and that it does not contain only empty lists
        outputlist.append([i,j,union])
```

You can even skip the di stage and jump to the combinations

```
outputlist=[]
for i,j in itertools.combinations(node,2):
    union=list(set(i[2]).intersection(set(j[2])))
    if union and not union[0]=='':#makes sure it is not an empty set and that it does not contain only empty lists
        outputlist.append([i[0], j[0],union])
```

Also I Would recomend leaving the animals as a set and assigning an empty list as python empty list.

### EDIT

If you stick to lists you might better use

```
union=filter(lambda x:x in i[2],j[2])
```

since type changing is a bit unefficient.

### All comes down to

```
import itertools    
output_list=filter(lambda x:x[2] and not x[2][0]=='',[[i[0],j[0],filter(lambda x:x in i[2],j[2])]for i,j in itertools.combinations(node,2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to solve your question is by using `combinations` from `itertools` with an intersection between your lists converted into a dicts module like this example:

```
from itertools import combinations

def compare(node, grouping=2):
    for elm1, elm2 in combinations(node, grouping):
        condition = set(elm1[-1]) & set(elm2[-1])
        if bool(condition) and condition != {''}:
            yield elm1[0], elm2[0], list(condition)

node = [['1001', '2008-01-06T02:12:13Z', ['']],
        ['1002', '2008-01-06T02:13:55Z', ['']],
        ['1003', '2008-01-06T02:13:00Z', ['Lion', 'Rhinoceros', 'Leopard', 'Panda']],
        ['1004', '2008-01-06T02:15:20Z', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Eagle', 'Panda', 'Tiger']],
        ['1005', '2008-01-06T02:15:48Z', ['Lion', 'Panda', 'Cheetah', 'Goat', 'Tiger']],
        ['1006', '2008-01-06T02:13:30Z', ['']],
        ['1007', '2008-01-06T02:13:38Z', ['Cheetah', 'Tiger', 'Goat']]]

final = list(compare(node))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['1003', '1004', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Panda']],
 ['1003', '1005', ['Lion', 'Panda']],
 ['1004', '1005', ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Panda']],
 ['1004', '1007', ['Tiger']],
 ['1005', '1007', ['Goat', 'Tiger', 'Cheetah']]]
```